# Vertically stacking a css gradient on top of a background image (not overlaid)

Tags: css, background-image, gradient

I've got a background image where the top row of pixels is a solid colour (it's a photo of a landscape). The idea would be to have this at the bottom of the page and then a CSS gradient above it that will stretch from the top of the page, stopping at the height of the image. There are lots of tutorials showing how to overlay/underlay the gradient, but they all assume that you want a full page gradient or the gradient overlaid on top of the background image.

What I have now is:

```
background: rgba(30, 53, 192, 1);

background: url("myimage.jpg") no-repeat center bottom, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #1E35C0 100%);
background: url("myimage.jpg") no-repeat center bottom, -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%,0% 100%, from(#000), to(#1E35C0));
background: url("myimage.jpg") no-repeat center bottom, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%,#1E35C0 100%);
background: url("myimage.jpg") no-repeat center bottom, -o-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%,#1E35C0 100%);
background: url("myimage.jpg") no-repeat center bottom, -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%,#1E35C0 100%);
background: url("myimage.jpg") no-repeat center bottom, linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #1E35C0 100%);

background-size: contain;
```

This has *almost* the desired effect. The CSS gradient is fine and the image is in the right place, but I don't know how to make the gradient stop above the image in a way that's nice and responsive. I can play with the percentages, but again, that only works if I know how tall the image is.

I know this is probably fairly easy in javascript, but I was hoping there's a clean CSS way to do it.

Comment: Is the problem in the fact that you are placing (`contain`ing) image of unknown proportions into container of unknown width, so you cannot predict its height, that you could otherwise set to background gradient as `background-size`?

Comment: I guess so, this is applied to `body` so the unknown width is the browser window. If I had the image fixed to be a particular height, this would be trivial I think. The image is of a landscape so I'd like to to be stretch the full page width and not distort, which would happen if I constrained the height.

Comment: if you know the aspect ratio of your image, you might be able to do it with vw units (viewport width).  I'll test it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your image has an aspect ratio of 4:1 (i.e. height is 25% of width), you can do this:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-image: url("http://ima.gs/transparent/000/000/200%C3%9750-200x50.png")
                  , linear-gradient(to top, transparent 25vw, #fff 25vw, #00f 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

The vw unit there in the gradient means percent of viewport width.  So if the background image will stretch the full width of the viewport, and its height is 25% of its width, then its height will be equal to 25vw and you can start the gradient at 25vw from the bottom, and end at the page top.

http://jsfiddle.net/8a5L20h4/